# how to popup video player window while click on image

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

am just beginner on visual studio 2010 and sharepoint coding..am doing code in visual studio 2010 and deploy it in sharepoint site as web part,

in this web part,

while click on static image it will popup video player window at the center of the screen and should play the video which is recently uploaded in asset libary.

recent modified date should display at the bottom of the static image..

can u please help me out to do this...

thanks in advance..

Comment: This is no way reated to classic asp. I have removed the tag

Comment: You really need to specify your problem better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SSP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx) method to show popup window in SharePoint 2010. You can have an [application page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx) which loads the video.

Comment: 1. Create an application Page which will load the video and other required details. 2. Edit your webpart to use SP.UI.Modal ... code to open the Application page you created in a popup window. Can you explain what is not clear? I will try to clarify.

Comment: i have done everything using sp.modalpopup,,problem is video player is stable for few seconds once getting refresh it will disappear..whats the issue i had

Comment: hmmmm What video player? And I think its problem with the video player .. did you try debugging in the client side?

Comment: no i havent try debugging...popup will disappear within  few seconds